# How to ensure a character is UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a strange issue here and I'm hoping that someone can shed some light on this for me. I'm looking for *why* this behavior occurs and how I can overcome it with PHP.

I have a directory with names of people and some of those names use ASCII characters. The one that I'm having an issue with is the e-acute `é`. I am using `scandir` to get the contents of the directory. One of the names containing the e-acute fails, while others using the same character do not fail. I've copied the characters into my IDE and the character that scandir fails on, reports that it is a regular `e`, although that not what I'm visually looking at; these characters look identical to me.

These are the characters that succeed and fail:

```
é This one shows as a regular 'e' and fails with scandir
é This one shows as e-acute and succeeds with scandir
```

Can someone tell me why this is? Also, is there a way to do a conversion on these types of characters so that I can be sure that scandir will not fail?

I should mention that I am already using a UTF8 header at the top of the script.

Comment: It's different. I'm not using a database here, and my question is *why* this behavior is happening. If I understand the **why** then I can fix it.

Comment: which os? version? it sounds like a file system\os issue, not a code\php one

Comment: @nogad, I'm using this on Windows 7.

Comment: Assuming NTFS, filenames are stored as UTF16; but generally speaking Windows fopen uses ANSI (locale-specific)

Comment: @MarkBaker, Mark, it is NTFS. Let me ask you this... When development is complete, I will be using a Linux box to host. Will the issue be resolved by using Linux or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Not a good idea to try and use filesystem for this, especially if you want it to work cross-platform.... [what charset encoding is used for filenames and paths on linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-charset-encoding-is-used-for-filenames-and-paths-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Mark. I'll have a look at it now.

Comment: As a recommendation.... generate a simple unique alphanumeric filename/directoryname to use for each file on the filesystem, and use a table on a db to reference a UTF-8 name with the filesystem name

Comment: I have to say, this whole UTF-8 thing is a nightmare. I don't understand why it is that there is no native PHP function that can detect a bad byte stream, or in my case, invalid characters. I like your suggestion, and as a final solution, I will use it, but there is something in me that thinks that there has to be some other way of either converting bad characters or at the very least, having a way to test for these characters so I can convert them programmatically.